# Being a theoretician at a business university?

Tags: soft-question

I'm currently on the job market and I've seen some open faculty positions in computer science at a business university (which is quite reputable among its kind). While the job opening doesn't emphasize TCS, it's written in such a broad way that my current line of work could easily fit the profile.

That said, I'm having some concerns before applying:

1. Will it be difficult/impossible to get PhD students that are interested in TCS?
2. Should I expect a negative bias from funding agencies regarding grants, because of me being at a "non-technical/science"-oriented university?

Comment: I am confused about what is a "business university"

Comment: There are lots of theoreticians at business schools, but they are typically concentrated at a small number of schools that have strong operations research groups, which is closely related to TCS. Are there other people doing TCS kinds of things at this department? If you would be the only one, I expect you would have no fun there. If there are others, it sounds like a reasonable choice.